# How do you get the code and examples formatted for SO examples?

Tags: discussion

I've just started with SO and I already feel as if I'm making a lot of work for the mods because I don't know how to make my code or data snippet examples look "pretty".

If it makes a difference, I'm primarily working in R.

Yes, I've read some of the other posts here, but they seem to be talking mostly about what the CONTENT of the example should be, not how it looks/the FORMAT.

I come from a non-programming statistical environment, so any advice that starts with the word "just" and some assumptions about underlying knowledge base is likely to be over my head :-)

Thanks in advance and regards!

Example of reproducible data created with dput():

```
df <-structure(list(userID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), timeStamp = c(1L, 3L, 
6L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 47L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 82L, 83L, 
90L, 91L, 102L), var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), 
    var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "y", class = "factor"), 
    varN = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N", class = "factor"), 
    sessID1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3.1, 
    3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2), sessID2 = c(1.1, 1.1, 
    1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
    3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3)), .Names = c("userID", "timeStamp", 
"var1", "var2", "varN", "sessID1", "sessID2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Example of data snippet/example:

```
   userID timeStamp var1 var2 varN sessID1 sessID2
1       1         1    x    y    N     1.0     1.1
2       1         3    x    y    N     1.0     1.1
3       1         6    x    y    N     1.0     1.1
4       1        40    x    y    N     1.1     1.2
5       1        42    x    y    N     1.1     1.2
6       1        43    x    y    N     1.1     1.2
7       1        47    x    y    N     1.1     1.2
8       2         5    x    y    N     2.0     2.1
9       2         8    x    y    N     2.0     2.1
10      3         2    x    y    N     3.0     3.1
11      3         5    x    y    N     3.0     3.1
12      3        38    x    y    N     3.1     3.2
13      3        39    x    y    N     3.1     3.2
14      3        39    x    y    N     3.1     3.2
15      3        82    x    y    N     3.2     3.3
16      3        83    x    y    N     3.2     3.3
17      3        90    x    y    N     3.2     3.3
18      3        91    x    y    N     3.2     3.3
19      3       102    x    y    N     3.2     3.3
```

Comment: Thanks!  If you want to post as an answer, I'll upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comments.

Select the portion you wish to modify and then click `B` just above the entry box to make it bold, click `I` to make it italic, click the world symbol to add a clickable link to it, click the double quotes to turn it into a quote, click `{}` to turn it into code, etc.

One can also just indent lines by 4 spaces to turn them into code lines.

Inline code is surrounded by backticks.

To add an image at the current point click on the terminal icon above the entry box or press ctrl-g .

There is more info on markdown editing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and questions about stackoverflow itself are normally asked at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

SO uses Google Prettify for formatting the code blocks.

Prettify has a handler for R.

To prettify an R code block, you precede it with:

`<!-- language: lang-r -->`

Here is a prettified R block taken from this [page](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/html/b2.html):

```r
# Goal: To do sorting.
#
# The approach here needs to be explained. If `i' is a vector of
# integers, then the data frame D[i,] picks up rows from D based
# on the values found in `i'.
#
# The order() function makes an integer vector which is a correct
# ordering for the purpose of sorting.

D <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,1), y=c(7,19,2,2))
D

# Sort on x
indexes <- order(D$x)
D[indexes,]

# Print out sorted dataset, sorted in reverse by y
D[rev(order(D$y)),]
```